# The Polyline is not showing in flutter but the directions api is enabled and the current position is not updating

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

1. The map draw polygons and markers but the polyline is not showing, the code is the following:

```
GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                onCameraIdle: _onCameraIdle,
                polygons: getPolygonList(zonesCubit.state.zonesCubit.data!, spotsCubit, zonesCubit) : {},
                polylines: {
                  const Polyline(
                    points: [LatLng(-74.813255, 11.004145), LatLng(-74.81268, 11.003933), LatLng(-74.809933, 11.002921), LatLng(-74.809641, 11.002813)],
                    polylineId: PolylineId("howto"),
                  ),
                },
                markers: Marker(
                          markerId: const MarkerId("CURRENT_USER"),
                          position: currentPosition,
                          icon: carIcon
                ),
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: referencePoint, zoom: currentZoom),
              ),
```

2. the marker position that represents the user current position is not being updated on map, but when re-run the app the marker now is in the new position, but only when re-run the app, the code is the following:

```
Marker(
                markerId: const MarkerId("CURRENT_USER"),
                position: currentPosition,
                icon: carIcon)
```

and to detect user position change i´m using [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) , the code is the following:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final locationSettings = LocationSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 5);
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
            (Position position) {
              setState(() {
                currentPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
              });
              getit<Logger>().i("current device location: $currentPosition");
          print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : '${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}');
        }
    );
  }
```

what could be happening?

I´m expecting draw the polyline and update the marker when the position is being updated